# Theano / Chainer Reporting Not Reporting Correct Free VRAM on K80 with 12GB RAM

Tags: theano, nvidia, theano-cuda, tesla, chainer

System:
Ubuntu 16.04.2
cudnn 5.1, CUDA 8.0

I have theano installed from git (latest version).

When I run the generate sample from https://github.com/yusuketomoto/chainer-fast-neuralstyle/tree/resize-conv, it reports back out of memory whether CPU or GPU is used.

```
python generate.py sample_images/tubingen.jpg -m models/composition.model -o sample_images/output.jpg -g 0

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:
 https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

/home/ubuntu/Theano/theano/sandbox/cuda/__init__.py:558: UserWarning: Theano flag device=gpu* (old gpu back-end) only support floatX=float32. You have floatX=float64. Use the new gpu back-end with device=cuda* for that value of floatX.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Using gpu device 0: Tesla K80 (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 95.0% of memory, cuDNN 5105)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate.py", line 45, in <module>
    y = model(x)
  File "/home/ubuntu/chainer-fast-neuralstyle/net.py", line 56, in __call__
    h = F.relu(self.b2(self.c2(h), test=test))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/links/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 108, in __call__
    deterministic=self.deterministic)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/functions/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 326, in convolution_2d
    return func(x, W, b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/function.py", line 199, in __call__
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/function.py", line 310, in forward
    return self.forward_gpu(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/functions/connection/convolution_2d.py", line 90, in forward_gpu
    y = cuda.cupy.empty((n, out_c, out_h, out_w), dtype=x.dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cupy/creation/basic.py", line 19, in empty
    return cupy.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 88, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__init__ (cupy/core/core.cpp:6333)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 280, in cupy.cuda.memory.alloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:5988)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 431, in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:9256)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 447, in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:9162)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 342, in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool.malloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:7817)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 368, in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool.malloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:7592)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 260, in cupy.cuda.memory._malloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:5930)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 261, in cupy.cuda.memory._malloc (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:5851)
  File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 35, in cupy.cuda.memory.Memory.__init__ (cupy/cuda/memory.cpp:1772)
  File "cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx", line 207, in cupy.cuda.runtime.malloc (cupy/cuda/runtime.cpp:3429)
  File "cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx", line 130, in cupy.cuda.runtime.check_status (cupy/cuda/runtime.cpp:2241)
cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation: out of memory
```

-

```
import theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops as sbcuda
sbcuda.cuda_ndarray.cuda_ndarray.mem_info()
(500105216L, 11995578368L)
```

-

```
lspci -vvv |grep -i -A 20 nvidia
00:04.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80]
Physical Slot: 4
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Region 1: Memory at 400000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16G]
Region 3: Memory at 800000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
Region 5: I/O ports at c000 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

What exactly do those numbers mean? Theano/Chainer only has access to ~500MB of VRAM?

Comment: It's possible that your GPUs have "zombie" allocations that are using memory, or else some other process on the GPU is using memory.  If all of that seems strange to you, you might try inspecting the output of `nvidia-smi` and/or rebooting the system and re-run your test, to see if most of the memory is then available.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by completely uninstalling theano. I was confused as to why importing chainer displayed the theano warnings, but it was doing that. Uninstalling theano allowed the chainer script to work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by completely uninstalling theano. I was confused as to why importing chainer displayed the theano warnings, but it was doing that. Uninstalling theano allowed the chainer script to work.